# Echoing CodeIgniter File Uploading Class upload->data() array

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I created a form in CodeIgniter framework that successfully uploads an image using the tutorial in the CodeIgniter manual (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html), but when I try to grab the file name, the following code is simply returning 'resize/user/w'. Any thoughts are appreciated!

```
$type = 'user';   
$imageData = $this->upload->data();

foreach ($imageData as $info) {
   $url = 'resize/' . $type . '/' . $info['file_name'];
}

echo $url;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
echo $imageData["file_name"];
```

Comment: Thanks much! There I was over-complicating it. Story of my life. ha

Answer (score 3):

`print_r($imageData);` will display all the useful upload data from the [CI Upload Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

```
Array
(
[file_name]    => mypic.jpg
[file_type]    => image/jpeg
[file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
[full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
[raw_name]     => mypic
[orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
[client_name]  => mypic.jpg
[file_ext]     => .jpg
[file_size]    => 22.2
[is_image]     => 1
[image_width]  => 800
[image_height] => 600
[image_type]   => jpeg
[image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

You can reference the the properties you want directly as Cosmin Atanasiu said with `$imageData['file_name']`, etc.